# External server query not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap application.

Here is some of my code to query data from an external server:

```
function showDetail(stationID){
     $('#itemDetail').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/detailPage.php?stationId='+stationID, function(){
});
```

It works perfectly on my local machine, WAMP server, however when I compile the script and run on an actual device, Android, it does not work. The same thing applies to this form:

```
$('#addStationForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.post( 'http://www.mywebsite.com/add_parser.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        alert( response );
    });
    // disable default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also I have whitelisted my server, so that is not the problem.

Any help would be greatly appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get data from a server and load it into a dom element?

If so use the .ajax function to perform a http request to get the data from the sever.

Check the following doc with good examples
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also provide more info about the type of data you are going to request receive to help you further in the configuration of the ajax call parameters.

You can also use getJSON but depending on your data and needs.

**EDIT**

Post is a shorthand of the ajax function.
Make sure your PHP does have the correct content-type in the headers. That is very important
Like:

```
header("Content-Type:text/plain");
```

or

```
header("Content-Type:text/html");
```

depending what you need, want.

Also you can debug the HTTP response using firebug or any other tool out there, and let us know what you got.

Also try to use the verbose option of the function, give it a try. Make sure you specify correctly the **dataType** and the **data** parameters.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: "html" // DATA TYPE is ALSO VERY IMPORTANT
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
 .fail(function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
   alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
 });
```

Also, when you said "when I compile the script and run on an actual device, Android, it does not work.", what errors you got? use the FAIL function of the http request to print the errors (like in the example above).

Comment: the callback data is in html format, for the fist function.
Please how about the second function($.post) why is that not working.